# Limit of real functions of two variables

Tags: calculus

To calculate the $\lim _{ \left( x,y \right) \rightarrow \left( 0,0 \right)  }{ \frac { { x }^{ 4 }+{ y }^{ 4 } }{ { x }^{ 2 }+{ y }^{ 2 } }  } $, first we use curves $\alpha \left( t \right) =\left( t,t \right) $ and $\beta \left( t \right) =\left( t,{ t }^{ 2 } \right) $ that pass by $\left( 0,0 \right) $ point, in this case $\lim _{ \left( x,y \right) \rightarrow \left( 0,0 \right)  }{ \frac { { x }^{ 4 }+{ y }^{ 4 } }{ { x }^{ 2 }+{ y }^{ 2 } }  } =\lim _{ t\rightarrow o }{ \frac { 2{ t }^{ 4 } }{ 2{ t }^{ 2 } } =0 } $ and $\lim _{ \left( x,y \right) \rightarrow \left( 0,0 \right)  }{ \frac { { x }^{ 4 }+{ y }^{ 4 } }{ { x }^{ 2 }+{ y }^{ 2 } }  } =\lim _{ t\rightarrow o }{ \frac { { t }^{ 4 }+{ t }^{ 8 } }{ { t }^{ 2 }+{ t }^{ 4 } } =0 } $ . But to categorically affirm that the limit is zero, we use the definition of limit, to find the relation $\varepsilon =\varepsilon \left( \delta  \right) $. In this case it results $\varepsilon ={ \delta  }^{ 2 }$. In many cases this process of finding $\varepsilon =\varepsilon \left( \delta  \right) $ is difficult.

Is there any other method that can be used in such a way as to obviate the process of finding $\varepsilon =\varepsilon \left( \delta  \right) $ (limit demonstration) and thus affirming with certainty that $\lim _{ \left( x,y \right) \rightarrow \left( 0,0 \right)  }{ \frac { { x }^{ 4 }+{ y }^{ 4 } }{ { x }^{ 2 }+{ y }^{ 2 } }  }=0$ ?. If there a method on which theorem is based?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Use polar coordinates: write $x=r\cos t$ and $y=r\sin t$. Then
$$f(x,y)=\frac{x^4+y^4}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{r^4\cos^4t+r^4\sin^4 t}{r^2}
=r^2(\cos^4t+\sin^4t)\le2r^4.$$
So $f(x,y)\to0$ as $r\to0$, that is as $(x,y)\to(0,0)$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the inequality to reach the conclusion: $\dfrac{x^4+y^4}{x^2+y^2} \le x^2+y^2$

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{x^4-y^4}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{(x^2+y^2)^2-2x^2y^2}{x^2+y^2} \leqslant \frac{(x^2+y^2)^2}{x^2+y^2}=x^2+y^2$